# Given a matrix of size N*N. We need to find out number of locations of particular string

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

As the title of question suggests that we have to find the number of occurences of particular string in a grid of characters of size N(<=1000). We can only go diagonally. For Example

```
  5               //N
  B X A X X       //grid
  X A X X X       
  X B B X X
  X A X A X
  X X B X X
  ABA           //Finding its occurence in the above grid 

  Answer is 14
```

I don't know how to solve this question. I have seen people doing this with some kind of recursion (they say it's backtracking).

**What I have done till now**

I tried to solve this using BFS and it gives right answer for small cases but not giving anything for large N.

**My code for BFS that I have tried**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define pb push_back
#define nline puts("\n")
vector<pair<int,int> >v;
#define e .00000001
string s;
char ch[1000][1000];
int dx[4] = {1, 1, -1, -1};
int dy[4] = { -1, 1, 1, -1 };
char vis[1000][1000];
int n,total=0;
struct data
{
    int x,y;
    void set(int _x,int _y)
    {
        x=_x;
        y=_y;
    }
};

void bfs(data src)
{
    vis[src.x][src.y]=true;
    queue<data>Q;
    Q.push(src);
    int len=1;
    while(not Q.empty())
    {
        data ss=Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            int xx=dx[i]+ss.x;
            int yy=dy[i]+ss.y;
            if(len<=s.length()-1 and ch[xx][yy]==s[len] and xx>=0 and xx<n and yy>=0 and yy<n and (not vis[xx][yy]))
            {
                vis[xx][yy]=true;
                data tem;
                tem.set(xx,yy);
                Q.push(tem);
                len++;
            }
        }
    }
      if(len==s.length())total++;
}
int main() {
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    cin>>ch[i][j];
   cin>>s;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
           if(ch[i][j]==s[0])
          {
               data start;
               start.set(i,j);
               bfs(start);
               memset(vis,0,sizeof vis);
          }
       }
    }
      cout<<total<<endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me out? :)

Comment: @Maxim Pontyushenko Thank you sir for edits

Comment: I think you must set `vis` back to false some time so that the cells can be visited by subsequent recursive calls. Recursion to unvisited cells usually goes like this: Mark cell as visited; recurse as appropriate; reset cell to unvisited.

Comment: Just to make sure to get it right: `X` matches any of `A`, `B` ? The matches strings are formed by consecutive entries either in a given column or in a given row ? `Consecutive` means there is no wrap-around ( ie. in a given column, first line does not follow the last line ) ? You may traverse the matrix only by incrementing/decrementing row and column index in the same transition? Btw, probably a clerical error, `N` seems to be 5, not 8 ?

Comment: @collapsar Sorry sir updated

Comment: `grid[1][1] => grid[0][0] => grid[1][1]`   
Is it a valid `ABA` occurrence?

Comment: Everybody I know nobody likes to follow link but I am very new to everything and I am scared that i can  misguide you so here is problem link  http://www.codechef.com/problems/INSOMA2

Comment: is your language limited to A B and X?

Comment: @EvilTeach Sir,I don't think so,I think that is just for illustration purpose

Comment: @bitshiftleft I don't think BFS is the way to go, as you are going to visit every char more than once. Would a recursive solution also work?

Comment: @markiz Actually sir I have never understood recursion.So i will be obliged if you can help me understanding the solution to this problem

Comment: A recursive solution of DFS is easier here. Anyway, your loop logic inside is not correct. You will find only one occurrence for each starting point, which may miss some occurrences. If you are using BFS and a queue, you probably should store the current `len` together with the grid coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution, not what you asked for but I hope it helps.

We'll use a function to check how many occurrences are there for every element of the matrix. If `grid[1][1]` matches the first character of the string we need to check if the diagonal neighboring elements match the second character of the string. We could remove the first character of the string and simply call the same function on the neighboring elements with the new string.

(Python code but should be understandable-ish even if you don't know Python)

First we create a helper function to return the valid diagonal neighbors.

```
def valid_neighbors(i,j, N):
    # Returns a list of valid diagonal neighbors(Do not exceed matrix borders).
    neighbors = [(i-1, j-1), (i+1, j+1), (i+1, j-1), (i-1, j+1)]
    return [m for m in neighbors if  (0 <= m[0] < N) and (0 <= m[1] < N)]
```

Next is the recursive function that checks for occurrences (Comments explain the logic).

```
def find(matrix, N, i, j, string):
    occurrences = 0
    if string == matrix[i][j]:
        # Found one occurrence, nothing else to do.
        return 1
    if string[0] == matrix[i][j]:
        # First letter of the string match, seek for possible occurrences.
        for new_i, new_j in valid_neighbors(i, j, N):
            # Go over all valid diagonal moves
            if matrix[new_i][new_j] == string[1]:
                # If the char in the new location match the next character of the string,
                # recursively call this function with the new position and the input string
                # minus the first character ("ABCD" -> "BCD").
                occurrences += find(matrix, N, new_i, new_j, string[1:])
    # Finally return the number of occurrences found.
    return occurrences
```

That works on a single element of the matrix, we need to call the function for every element and sum the results.

```
def wrapper(matrix, string):
    # Call find on every element of the matrix and sum the results.
    occurrences = 0
    N = len(matrix)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            occurrences += find(matrix, N, i, j, string)
    return occurrences
```

You could build a caching mechanism to improve performance.

Running the code on the input matrix:

```
mat = [
       ['B', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'X'],
       ['X', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
       ['X', 'B', 'B', 'X', 'X'],
       ['X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X'],
       ['X', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'X']
       ]
print wrapper(mat, "ABA")
14
```